# R: removing the '$' symbols

Tags: regex, r

I have downloaded some data from a web server, including prices that are formatted for humans, including $ and thousand separators.

```
> head(m)
[1] $129,900 $139,900 $254,000 $260,000 $290,000 $295,000
```

I was able to get rid of the commas, using

```
m <- sub(',','',m)
```

but

```
m <- sub('$','',m)
```

does not remove the dollar sign. If I try `mn <- as.numeric(m)` or as.integer I get an error message:

> Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

and the result is:

```
> head(m)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

How can I remove the $ sign? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 dat <- gsub('[$]','',dat)
 dat <- as.numeric(gsub(',','',dat))
 > dat
 [1] 129900 139900 254000 260000 290000 295000
```

In one step

```
 gsub('[$]([0-9]+)[,]([0-9]+)','\\1\\2',dat)
[1] "129900" "139900" "254000" "260000" "290000" "295000"
```

Comment: Yes, that works well, thank you!!  `m <- data.frame(gsub('[$]', '', m))`

Comment: Using `gsub("[$,]", "", dat)` as the regex should do that in one step

Comment: Thanks Dason, that's even easier!

Comment: @Dason Right! mine looks ugly now :(

Comment: As yet another option, there is also the `fixed` argument that would allow you to turn off the regex interpretation of `$`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.  It means replace anything that is not a digit with the empty string:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", dat))
```

or to remove anything that is neither a digit nor a decimal:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", dat))
```

UPDATE: Added a second similar approach in case the data in the question is not representative.

Comment: Be careful though if you have decimals in your numbers because this will remove the decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

you could also use:

```
x <- c("$129,900", "$139,900", "$254,000", "$260,000", "$290,000", "$295,000")

library(qdap)
as.numeric(mgsub(c("$", ","), "", x))
```

**yielding:**

```
> as.numeric(mgsub(c("$", ","), "", x))
[1] 129900 139900 254000 260000 290000 295000
```

If you wanted to stay in base use the `fixed = TRUE` argument to gsub:

```
x <- c("$129,900", "$139,900", "$254,000", "$260,000", "$290,000", "$295,000")
as.numeric(gsub("$", "", gsub(",", "", x), fixed = TRUE))
```